# Remove all item from queue c++

Tags: c++, linked-list, queue, nodes

If I have a queue implemented as a series of nodes (value, pointer to next node), what would be the best way to transverse that queue and check for a specific value, and edit the queue such that all nodes containing that value would be removed. But the order of the queue would otherwise remain.

Ok here is the header describing all the functions

```
class queue
{
  public:
    queue(); // constructor - constructs a new empty queue.
    void enqueue( int item ); // enqueues item.
    int dequeue();  // dequeues the front item.
    int front();   // returns the front item without dequeuing it.
    bool empty();  // true iff the queue contains no items.
    int size();  // the current number of items in the queue.
    int remove(int item); // removes all occurrances of item 
      // from the queue, returning the number removed.

  private:
    class node  // node type for the linked list 
    {
       public:
           node(int new_data, node * next_node ){
              data = new_data ;
              next = next_node ;
           }
           int data ;
           node * next ;
    };

    node* front_p ;
    node* back_p ;
    int current_size ; // current number of elements in the queue.
};
```

and here is the queue.cpp

```
#include "queue.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

queue::queue()
{
   front_p = NULL;
   back_p = NULL;
   current_size = 0;
}

void queue::enqueue(int item)
{
    node* newnode = new node(item, NULL);
   if (front_p == NULL) //queue is empty
        front_p = newnode;
    else
        back_p->next = newnode;
   back_p = newnode;
   current_size ++;
}

int queue::dequeue()
{
   //if there is only one node
    int value = front_p->data;
    if (front_p == back_p)
    {
        front_p = NULL;
        back_p = NULL;
    }
    //if there are two or more
    else
    {
        node* temp = front_p;
        front_p = temp->next;
        delete temp;
    }
    current_size --;
    return value;
}

int queue::front()
{
    if (front_p != NULL)
        return front_p->data;
}

bool queue::empty()
{
    if (front_p == NULL && back_p == NULL)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

int queue::size()
{
    return current_size;
}

int queue::remove(int item)
{
//?????
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _check for a specific value_? Check if a specific value is present in the queue?

Comment: Well, you just traverse it and remove nodes as you go. Without seeing your implementation, I don't really see how we could help you here.

Comment: The best way would would be to write some code that does exactly what you said. Sorry if this seems facetious but what kind of answer were you expecting? Unless you give some idea of what the problem is (by posting code or explaining what it is you don't understand for instance) it's hard to help. I would guess that you are stuck on how to remove nodes from a list, but if that is the case then please say so.

Comment: A queue is not a good data structure if you need to modify/remove items in the middle of it. Are you using e.g. `std::queue` or your own home-grown queue? If the latter, are you using `std::list`?

Comment: If you are using e.g. `std::list` for the queue, or another container exposing a standard iterator interface, consider [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove).

Comment: Not your question (I don't have time right now), but your dequeue method has a memory leak. When you remove the last node in your queue you don't delete it.

Comment: A node is comprised of an integer value, and a pointer to the next node in the queue. If there is no next node, then the pointer simply points to null. So `|_2_|__|->|_3_|__|->NULL` is a queue with two nodes, the first node contains a 2 and points to the next node, which contains a 3.

Answer (score 2):

You need to traverse the list, checking the values of each node. If you see a sequence A -> B -> C, where B is the value that you want to remove, you need to change the link from A to point to C instead of B.

To facilitate this, you'll need to keep a reference to the last node you saw as well as the current one. If the current node's value is equal to the one to remove, change the last node's  next pointer to the current node's next pointer. Make sure to free the current node's memory before continuing on.

Answer (score 0):

If your queue exposes standard iterators, the best way would be to use a standard algorithm:

```
queue.erase(std::remove(queue.begin(), queue.end(), value_to_remove), queue.end());
```